# Facebook Album Contributers via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

On August 27th Facebook released on their website the ability to add contributors to a specific photo album. This is a specific entitlement that allows other users to add photos to an album - not a Page or an Event - a private photo album.

I can not find any reference to it in the Facebook API. The latest API was released on August 22nd so it might not include this feature but if someone around here is 'in the know' it will be nice to get some insight into this feature and APi functionality / release date.

Thanks,
Liad